# assign value to javascript variable from C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

A comma separated string value is returned from DB and I would like to assign it to a javascript variable.
Hidden fields are not an option. 
Unabele to get the data into js variable. This is what I have tried

**ASPX:**

```
<script>
var Collection = <%GetCodes();%>
$(document).ready(function () {
  alert(Collection);
</script>
```

**C#:**

```
public string GetCodes()
    {
        datatable dt = function to get data;
        return Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["codes"]);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `var Collection = '<%=GetCodes();%>';`?

Comment: I get an alert that says 'undefined'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
var Collection = <%=GetCodes()%>;

$(document).ready(function () {
  alert(Collection);
});
</script>
```

(Add the `=`, remove the semi-colon).

Think of the use of `=` as part of an evaluation (i.e. the return of your `GetCodes()` method), and without the `=` as a call on the method without concern with what's returned.

Note also, your parentheses were not balanced, that could've contributed to your problems!? Fixed in my code above anyway.

---

*As an aside: be careful mixing JS and C# in this way. When they're this tightly coupled things can horribly wrong, very fast.*

Comment: The result was a string. So it should be `var Collection = '<%=GetCodes()%>';` Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
    var Collection = <%=GetCodes()%>;
    $(document).ready(function () {
      alert(Collection); 
});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Value returned from GetCodes() shouldn't be in `'` or `"`?

Comment: No they aren't. They are like - abc,def,ghi